# How do I encrypt a password in Griffon?

Tags: griffon

I tried to encrypt a password in Griffon, but I don't know how to do that. Usually I'd use md5 in another language, but what in griffon?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
if (sql.firstRow("SELECT userID FROM tbluser WHERE userID = ${model.userID}") != null) {
    // usually in SQL like this
    user.executeUpdate("UPDATE tbluser SET username = ${model.username}, password = md5(${model.password}), level = ${model.level} WHERE userID = ${model.userID}")

    edt {
        int index = model.listUser.findIndexOf{it['userID'] == model.userID}
        model.listUser[index] += [username: model.username, password: model.password, level: model.level] --> how to do md5 here?
    }
} else {
    user.add(userID: model.userID, username: model.username, password: model.password, level: model.level) --> and here?

    edt { model.listUser << [userID: model.userID, username: model.username, password: model.password, level: model.level] }
}
```

I just get a sample code about it and it worked.

Here the code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
String generateMD5(String s) {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        digest.update(s.bytes);
        return new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(32, '0')
}
```

for my case: `generateMD5(model.password)`

Answer (score 1):

Per se encryption is not related to Griffon, as it's just a transformation of a character/byte array. However there's a bcrypt plugin available that applies the BCrypt algorithm http://artifacts.griffon-framework.org/plugin/bcrypt

More information on BCrypt can be found at http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't work. Am I wrong using it?
I use it like this: encodeAsString(model.password) and also tried use it like: encodeAsBcrypt(model.password). it gives me error like: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Object.encodeAsString() and groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Object.encodeAsBcrypt()

Comment: The additional methods are applied to String, so you must call them directly on the password property -> `model.password.encodeAsBcrypt()`. Looks like the documentation described the wrong names, I'll fix that.

Comment: Hi, i just get it solved by using the code above. Btw thanks aalmiray.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to griffon but i think this can help you.
I hope i could help you with this.

[Codesearch Griffon MD5](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/25242810)

Comment: Thanks, Galexrt.

it's from griffon.util right? MD5.encode().

i have tried it but it give me error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: griffon/util/MD5

am i wrong when use it, i wonder..